# CakePHP 3 belongsToMany Validation

Tags: validation, cakephp, model, has-and-belongs-to-many, cakephp-3.0

I am struggling with how to do validation with belongsToMany relationships.  Namely, the classic recipes/ingredients relationship.  I would like a recipe to always have an ingredient on create or edit.  What would my validation look like in my RecipesTable?  I have tried:

```
$validator->requirePresence('ingredients')->notEmpty('ingredients')
```

As well as

```
$validator->requirePresence('ingredients._ids')->notEmpty('ingredients._ids')
```

The second one works in that my form doesn't validate, but it does not add the `error` class to the input.  I am setting up the input with a field name of `ingredients._ids`.

I am also having trouble with creating the data to pass to `$this->post` in my tests in order to successfully add a record in my test.  My data in my test looks like:

```
$data = [
    'ingredients' => [
        '_ids' => [
             '2'
        ]
    ];
```

And of course I'm doing the post in my test with `$this->post('/recipes/add', $data);`

I'm not passing the required rules for ingredients in my test.

Comment: What exactly does "_I'm not passing the required rules ..._" mean? Are there any validation errors? If so, are they related to your former validation problem, or this a different problem?

Comment: I probably should have divided this up into two questions. Are you able to verify how the validation rules should be set up in the Table Object to require ingredients on create or update of a recipe record?  If I can solve that, my tests might naturally fall into place.

Comment: You've already found the answer, that is indeed how it had to be done. I wanted to wait with answer until I knew whether this would get merged: **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/pull/5947** It finally did, and when following the naming conventions (`ingredients._ids` for the fieldname, `ingredients` for the entity property name), your input field should now be able to pick up the error automatically.

Comment: Thank you for the reference to the pull request, I'm glad it got merged. Will this also take care of adding the error class to the element in addition to displaying the validation message?

Comment: Yes it does, it should work exactly as it does with all other fields, the wrapper gets the `error` class, and the message element is being appended in the wrapper.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved how to set up the validators.  In the recipe Table validator:

```
$validator->add('ingredients', 'custom', [
    'rule' => function($value, $context) {
        return (!empty($value['_ids']) && is_array($value['_ids']));
    },
    'message' => 'Please choose at least one ingredient'
]);
```

However, the validation message was not being displayed on the form, so I'm doing a `isFieldError` check:

```
        <?php if ($this->Form->isFieldError('ingredients')): ?>
            <?php echo $this->Form->error('ingredients'); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

I'm using multiple checkboxes in my view file versus a multi-select.

And with that, I'm getting my validation message on the form.

As I thought, my tests fell into place once I figured out the validator.  What I show above is indeed correct for passing data in the test.

Comment: Using Cake3/4 afterMarshal event you can actually solve the form display error by using e.g. `if ($entity->getError('ingredients') && !$entity->getError('ingredients._ids')) {
            $entity->setError('ingredients._ids', $entity->getError('ingredients'));
        }`

Answer (score 2):

I will have desired to add this answer as a comment of Kris answer but I do not have enough reputation.

Alternatively, to solve the issue with validation message not being displayed on the form, you can add these two line in your controller.

```
if(empty($this->request->data['ingredients']['_ids']))
    $yourentity->errors('ingredients', 'Please choose at least one ingredient');
```